# Sorting a Backbone Collection After initialization

Tags: backbone.js

I am using Backbone.js to render a list of items e.g Books. After the list is rendered, there are options for user to sort them. So if user clicks on Sort By Title, or Sort By Author Name the list will sort itself on the client side.

```
  window.Book = Backbone.Model.extend({
   defaults: {
     title: "This is the title",
     author: "Name here"
   },
```

What is the best way to accomplish this sort using in the context of a Backbone application. Do I use a jQuery dom sorter in the AppView?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

There's a discussion on this very topic that you might want to look at: https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone/issues/41.

The short of it is that when a user selects 'sort by X', you can:

1. Set the `comparator` function on the Collection
2. Call the Collection's `sort` function (which will trigger a `sort` event)
3. Listen for the `sort` event in your View, and (clear and) redraw the items

Another way to handle steps 1 & 2 is to have your own method that calls the Collection's `sortBy` method and then triggers a custom event that your View can listen to.

But it seems to be the case that clearing and redrawing is the easiest (and maybe even the fastest) way to sort your View's and keep them in sync with your Collection's sort order.

Comment: Thanks rulfzid. I am going to try this approach out

Comment: Correction for 2.  the `sort` event is the one that gets fired when the Collection's sort function is called, not `reset`

Comment: In your view you need to listen to the 'sort' event not 'reset' (I think that's older versions of backbone). Pass the same collection to the view and use: this.listenTo(this.collection, 'sort', this.render);

Comment: Will that create a ton of zombie views? It seems that every time you "sort" you are creating new Backbone view objects which takes additional time and space and leaving old view objects hanging around.

Answer (score 51):

You can update the comparator function and then call the sort method.

```
// update comparator function
collection.comparator = function(model) {
    return model.get('name');
}

// call the sort method
collection.sort();
```

The view will be automatically re-rendered.

Comment: and then how does one do descending?

Comment: .. found it... use a minus sign 'return -model.get('name');'

Comment: @Kirby, I would think that descending order with a `-` sign would only work for `Number` attributes, not `String` ones?

Answer (score 12):

`comparator` is what you need

```
var PhotoCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Photo,
    comparator: function(item) {
        return item.get('pid');
    }
});
```

Comment: Isn't comparator used for sorting the collection during initialization. After the list has been displayed, the user have actions to re-sort them in different ways and that's what I need to figure out.

Answer (score 4):

This way works well and enables sorting by all `attributes` dynamically and handles `ascending` or `descending`:

```
var PhotoCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Photo,
    sortByField: function(field, direction){
            sorted = _.sortBy(this.models, function(model){
                return model.get(field);
            });

            if(direction === 'descending'){
                sorted = sorted.reverse()
            }

            this.models = sorted;
    }
});
```

Comment: multiply by `-1` in the sort function to avoid sorting twice.

Comment: @Leo that would only be useful if field is numeric

Comment: After sorting, I have empty values are coming on the top. How can I move these empty values to the bottom ?

Comment: @Jyothu I would recommend either removing the empty items from your collection or sorting over a fields which denotes the empty values by some index, which gets sorted to the bottom.