# Marionette model.fetch() not working as expected

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

I want to retrieve a model of particular id number into my view. Here are how my controller looks like (API is working fine):

**Controller**

```
var EventController = Marionette.Controller.extend({
    initialize: function(options){
        this.model = options.model;
        this.mainRegion = options.mainRegion;
    },

    edit: function(id) {
        var _me = this;
        //this is my model
        var event = new Event({
            id: id
        });
        event.fetch({
            success: function(){
                 //this is my layout
                _me.eventLayout = new EventView({
                    model: event
                });
                _me.mainRegion.show(_me.eventLayout);
            }
        });
     }
});
```

The scenario is like:

- My controller functions are getting called using a router.
- My main Layout i.e. eventLayout contain some regions which are eventViews all in Marionette.
- The model.fetch is successful and I can see the details fetched from the API.
- All the subviews of the mail Layout are getting rendered perfectly.
- None of the data meant for main Layout template is getting rendered . Its just the DOM that gets rendered but not the data.

Comment: I think both _me.eventLayout and _me.mainRegion are called approximately at same time so _me.mainRegion is rendered even if _.wrap method is not there properly. So try to make _me.mainRegion render after _me.eventLayout. You can use _.wrap method. Hope this helps.
You can refer to
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12004534/backbonejs-rendering-problems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
edit: function (id) {
   var _me = this, event, eventView;

   event = new Event({ id: id });
   eventView = new EventView({ model: event });

   event.fetch().done(function () {
       _me.mainRegion.show(eventView);
   });
}
```