# How to group backbone collection by model category, then sort each group by model rank

Tags: backbone.js, marionette, backbone-views, backbone-events

I am following David Sulc's tutorial on Marionette. 
http://davidsulc.com/blog/2012/04/15/a-simple-backbone-marionette-tutorial/ and in order to learn extending over it.

Now lets say each cat has a name, rank as well as **Category**

```
AngryCat = Backbone.Model.extend({
   urlRoot: '/api/cats',
   defaults: {
          name: "New Cat Name",
          category: "Red Cat"
  }
});
```

Now I want to make a composite view like this:

**Category 1: Red Cat (03 Cats)**

Cat 1

Cat 2

Cat 3

**Category 2: Blue Cat (02 Cats)**

Cat X

Cat Y

*How can I achieve this. Please help!*

Comment: Is your rank a number?

Comment: Yes it is a number. And man you changed my question entirely to the way you wanted to answer. I mean I wanted to create a MARIONETTE COMPOSITE VIEW from that. And now how do I render? or how will the view. I know groupby method of backbone, I wanted to enquire how to use it more on front end. And by the way, my question never had to deal with Rank. I mean I never how to categorise according to rank.

Comment: I changed the question because I thought it was what you were trying to ask.  Your question was difficult to understand and it's title suggested you wanted to be able to group and sort. You gave no marionette code as example of what you tried so I interpreted the question from what you stated.  Maybe you could open another question specifically focused on marionette composite views with code examples?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can probably achieve what you want to do by combining dcarson's code with my blog post on nested views: http://davidsulc.com/blog/2013/02/03/tutorial-nested-views-using-backbone-marionettes-compositeview/

You need to provide a collection of groups to the composite view. The composite view's item views will be a collection view displaying the cats in that group (i.e. what is done in the linked blog post).

Comment: I think site is down.

Comment: Sorry about that, it should be back up. If not, try again in a few hours (DNS issue, might need to propagate).

Answer (score 8):

You can use the `groupBy` function to group your `AngryCat` models by their by `category` property, then use `sortBy` to sort each group individually by its rank (I am assuming your model has a property named `rank` that is a number). I also assume you have an intial collection variable named `angryCats` that contains your models.

```
var groups = angryCats.groupBy(function(ac) {
    return ac.get("category");
});

groups.each(function(group, key) {

     // This will output the category name & item count
     console.log(key + " " + group.length + " items"); 

     group.sortBy(function (model) {
         return model.get("rank");
     });

     group.each(function(model) {
         // This will output the model name
         console.log(model.get("name")); 
     });

});
```

Additionally, if your wanted to sort each group by a string property of the model, such as the `name` property, you'll need to create a new locally scoped `angryCats` collection out of each group (the groups are arrays), then sort each collection by [using a comparator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7005411/sorting-a-backbone-collection-after-initialization) as the linked question outlines.

Hope this helps