# How to sort Backbone.fetch by data?

Tags: javascript, python, json, backbone.js

I have such question:
I have 2 collections (Dishes and Categories).
I have backend method that returns me JSON with Dish by Category.
How to make sorting of my data in HTML in such way - on click Category button i

Answer (score 0):

Like this?
[Sorting a Backbone Collection After initialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7005411/sorting-a-backbone-collection-after-initialization)

"have your own method that calls the Collection's sortBy method and then triggers a custom event that your View can listen to."